# Facebook Graph API - /{user-id}/feed limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to use the facebook /{user-id}/feed to read facebook posts for a specific user. Before I go down the long road of setting up the Graph API, just wanted to get some quick questions answered.

How far back in time does the /{user-id}/feed go to return data?
Can I filter for specific words?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API returns all posts for a user since they joined. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed/

Keyword filtering was available using FQL, which is now depreciated. There's no way to do this using the Graph API.